# spacy bert uncased model. help cannot download

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, spacy

I am trying to run this on google colaboratory

`!python -m spacy download en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg`

I am looking to use the model for text classification.

but I cannot install this model, I keep getting this error:

```
2023-10-26 18:22:02.571699: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9342] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2023-10-26 18:22:02.571769: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:609] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2023-10-26 18:22:02.571814: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1518] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2023-10-26 18:22:02.580822: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-10-26 18:22:03.859736: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT

✘ No compatible package found for 'en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg' (spaCy
v3.7.2)
```

what should I do as I have installed the latest version of spaCy.
I appreciate and thank any help that you can give

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the model name `en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg` with `en_core_web_trf` due to the  [name change](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8243) of the transformer model in `spacy` from version `2.x` to `3.x`. In google colab, you may need to separately install `spacy_transformers` as well. Use the following commands:

```
!pip install spacy[transformers]
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```

Once the model is downloaded, you can use it via:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')
```

Tested it with `spacy 3.6.1` and it's working fine!